# unable to implement deeplink in the ionic capacitor application

Tags: ionic-framework, deep-linking, capacitor

I am working on a project and it’s related to ionic capacitor application, I am trying to implement deeplink in my project(open my app when the link is clicked on a website)

I have installed the plugin

npm install @ionic-native/deeplinks

and I am trying to run a command  i.e

ionic cordova plugin add ionic-plugin-deeplinks --variable URL_SCHEME=demo --variable DEEPLINK_SCHEME=https --variable DEEPLINK_HOST=demo.com --variable ANDROID_PATH_PREFIX=/

But I am facing the error :

[ERROR] Refusing to run ionic cordova plugin inside a Capacitor project.

I’ve also tried the command

npm i ionic-plugin-deeplinks -variable URL_SCHEME=demo -variable DEEPLINK_SCHEME=https -variable DEEPLINK_HOST=demo.com -variable ANDROID_PATH_PREFIX=/

but facing the error :

npm ERR! code EINVALIDTAGNAME
npm ERR! Invalid tag name "URL_SCHEME=demo" of package "URL_SCHEME=demo": Tags may not have any characters that encodeURIComponent encodes

can someone help me with this implementation?